# Python subprocess stacking

Tags: python, subprocess

hi I got problem to program with python.
what i want to do is running Linux command in Python.

Here I have command "usbrh" this return 5 lines as below.

```
# usbrh -t

  27.49
  27.49
    
  Temperature
```

I want just get and display the value in second line, "27.49".

so I tried like

```
import subprocess
runcmd = subprocess.call(["usbrh", "-t"])
print (runcmd[0:5])
```

then get error like as below.

```
# python sample.py
27.47
27.47

Temperature
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sample.py", line 3, in <module>
    print (runcmd[0:5])
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I am using python 2.7 version.
does anyone help me?

Comment: The error message says it all no? subprocess.call() seems to returns an `int`, probably the exit code of the process, not the string you expect. There is a second problem as well: [0:5] is probably also not going to get you what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call), `subprocess.call` returns the exit status of the command, which is an `int`.

You must use `subprocess.check_output` [if you want to handle the command output](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output).

Comment: thanks a lot!  program successfully ran! so happy to get answer super fast.

Comment: Happy to help. Please accept my answer as solution.